# BDD - how to deal with specification of cross cutting features?

Tags: bdd, gherkin

In BDD, how would you deal with the specification of cross cutting features?

Consider for example an application that allows working on a document. There are features like editing text or adding images to the document. Now there's an additional feature "Changelog" that should provide the ability to investigate any change that has been done to a document before.

Now here's my dilemma: Either the "Changelog" gets it's own spec but than it's kind of a never-ending feature. Whenever a new feature for editing the document is added I also need to add something to the "Changelog" feature. Or the "Changelog" is specified in all other features' specs by always sketching out which kind of entry should appear in the changelog after a certain operation. In this case I need to foresee the changelog feature when defining other features, and features that have already been defined and possibly implemented need refinement for the changelog feature.

Any practical advice how to solve this dilemma?

Answer (score 0):

I handle things like this by adding an extra assert step on any scenario that is relevant.

```
Given some set up
When I use a feature
Then something happens
And it is reflected in the changelog as a 'something happened' entry
```

The reason I would do it this way, rather than having a separate spec is that it sounds like the two actions are part of the same feature.  It wouldn't make sense to me to split them out into separate scenarios.  Any existing scenarios that would be broken by a change will be using the same step definition so will be updated when you make this test pass.

The downside of doing it this way is that the relevant tests that you would want to run when making changes to the changelog functionality are distributed through your test suite.  I would remedy this by tagging a relevant subset of the tests with @changelog and creating a test run to run only these tests.